# What are the specifications for the "Vansaya" crossbow in Sandpoint?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, rise-of-the-runelords

I am setting up Rise of the Runelords Anniversary edition and I was curious as to how I should tell my PC's what this +1 repeating crossbows worth is and if there are any special abilities tied to it. From the text it sounds to "epic" to not have some other ability than a +1 Attack Bonus. Also would I just treat it as a heavy crossbow for damage or does this have it's own requirements? The book is not very clear on any detail regarding it for referencing. The way this sounds by it being a +1 it's just a masterwork item that has a custom grip? Any ideas on pricing or ability scores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As-written, it should be treated as a standard magic +1 repeating crossbow. (Any item that says it is "+1" or some other number is magical.) Repeating crossbows come in a couple sizes (hand, light, & heavy) which will determine the base damage. ([Information on mundane variants can be found here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/armsAndArmor/weapons.html) ). Add a +1 enhancement bonus to attack and damage rolls made with the weapon.

The often forgotten thing here is that a lot of magic items are not mundane looking. Considering the price of making the weapon masterwork and magical, a little customization is a negligible additional cost.

An example that illustrates this from the [magic item creation rules](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html):

> At the time of creation, the creator must decide if the weapon glows
>   or not as a side-effect of the magic imbued within it. This decision
>   does not affect the price or the creation time, but once the item is
>   finished, the decision is binding.

In fact 30% of all [randomly generated magic weapons](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/weapons.html#_weapons) are visibly magical:

> Light Generation: Fully 30% of magic weapons shed light equivalent to
>   a light spell. These glowing weapons are quite obviously magical. Such
>   a weapon can't be concealed when drawn, nor can its light be shut off.
>   Some of the specific weapons detailed below always or never glow, as
>   defined in their descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the description also mentions that it is constructed of Darkwood and therefore half the weight of a standard crossbow of its size (and likely half the penalty for firing one handed) in addition to its other qualities...

Repeating crossbow:

- 250gp, 6 lbs. (light); or 400gp, 12 lbs. (heavy) base price
- 300gp masterwork prerequisite
- [2000gp +1 enhancement bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values)
- 10gp × standard weight in lbs. Darkwood material

Light: 2610gp, 3 lbs.
Heavy: 2820gp, 6 lbs.

That's an impressive piece of firepower! 5 shots with free action reloads!

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing the reference/source that mentions the construction being of Darkwood.   Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how this site is a bit different from discussion forums.  Thanks for participating, and  Happy Gaming!